# Creating and returning multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I read on some ways to dynamically create and use a 2D array, and I've settled on this way:

file:

```
5 4
+---+
|xxx|
|xxx|
+---+
```

main.c:

```c
char** loadArray() {
    FILE *in = fopen("file", "r");

    int w, h;
    fscanf(in, "%d %d\n", &w &h);

    char (*buf)[w] = malloc(sizeof(char[h][w]));

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        fscanf(in, "%s\n", buf[i]);
    }

    fclose();

    return buf;
}

int main() {
    char** array = loadArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // magic number, only because I know the size
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

While this does compile, it gives a warning: `incompatible pointer types returning 'char (*)[w]' from a function with result type 'char **'`, and segfaults if I try to run it.

Several questions (mainly for C, but C++ specific answers are welcome for future reference, when I get there):

1. What is the correct return type for a multidimensional array? The warning isn't quite helpful I think, since it offers a variable term, which I obviously don't have until I read the file.
2. At this point, I'm just trying to get returning 2D arrays to work, but when I do and move on, I'm going to need the dimensions of the array for proper usage later on. My first idea would be to return structs instead, where I can save the dimension and the array itself. However, after further thought, the variable size makes me think that I wouldn't be able to have a single struct template to use as the function's return type, and I would have to find some other way to get the size along with the array. Are ideas?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The usual answer: Just use `std::vector`. That is a dynamic array of objects, which knows its own size, and whose elements can themselves be `vector`s, and so on.

Comment: C and C++ are very different with respect to this kind of question. Your example code has me thinking that you are merely using C constructs? If so remove the C++ tag, please.

Comment: I see, thank you for the suggestions for the C++ side, but I'm still looking for a C solution.

Comment: Do you `malloc` enough room for a `C` string? Remember that the string has to contain `zero` at the end.

Comment: I seem to be doing fine without the extra null byte at the end, as I am simply trying to "represent a portion of an 80x24 display". No mucking around with the string itself, I just need to be able to print it out. Is it really an issue? I originally thought of scanning a character at a time, but that sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: `char **` and `char (*)[w]` are two very different pointer types. Also the second one is a pointer to a variable length array type, which cannot be used as the return type of a function. Perhaps you would be better off `malloc`ing an array of `char *` and `malloc`ing the memory for each row individually.

Comment: The %s in scanf will write  a nul-terminated string to memory whether you leave room or not.  It is undefined behavior if it goes out of bounds.

Comment: I went for the allocation method I did because I read that doing it that way will guarantee a contiguous memory block, which seems to fit my purpose to represent a screen well. I can't think of a disadvantage of the memory being not guaranteed to be contiguous off the top of my head, but is there?

Comment: @stark Aside from reading a character at a time, is there a way to avoid that behavior? Actually, I think I'll replace it with `%[^\n]` since there might be space characters, but the question still stands.

Comment: The @stark comment explains why you should allocate extra byte at the end. This is a segfault part of a question. Also you should place a `@` character if you write someone.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer to pointer and pointer to array are quite different things. You can't return the array dimension as such in the return type so you'd have to use an incomplete array:

```
char (*(loadArray()))[] {
  ...
}
```

Evidently this is not very readable so you'd better pass through a `typedef`:

```
typedef char line[];

line* loadArray() {
  ...
}
```

You'd also have to get your hands on the dimensions `w` and `h`, so you'd have to pass pointers to the values as arguments. But that would be another question.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the correct return type for a multidimensional array?

There is no "correct" type, it all depends on how **you** want to represent the data and what architecture **you** want to design.

> The warning isn't quite helpful I think, since it offers a variable term

The warning is very helpful, because it indicates an error in the code - you are casting a pointer to an array to a pointer to a pointer. Ignoring that warning ultimately leads to `printf("%s\n", array[i]);` which is undefined behavior.

> Are ideas?

You may return a pointer to a dynamically allocated array of pointers to dynamically allocated array of values.

```
char **loadArray(void) {
    size_t w, h;
    // Initialize w and h.

    char **arr;
    arr = malloc(w * sizeof(*arr));
    if (!arr) return NULL;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < w; ++i) {
       arr[i] = malloc(h * sizeof(*arr[i]));
       if (!arr[i]) {
          for (size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
             free(arr[j]);
          }
          frer(arr);
          return NULL;
       }
   }

   // Fill arr from file. Handle errors. Handle deallocation.

   return arr;
}
```

which is the usual way to program in C and one would expect `char **` to act that way. I can thing of an example from POSIX , where `scandir` function takes a pointer to a double pointer `struct dirent ***namelist` argument which is assigned to a such dynamically allocated 2d array.

But let's take a bit over-engineered (or not) design (in mostly C-ish pseudocode):

```
// represents the thing
struct thething_s {
    char *string;
};
int thething_print(struct thething_s *t, FILE *f) {
   return fprintf(f, ....);
}
void thething_free(struct thething_s *t) {
   free(t->string);
}
int thething_load_from_file(struct thething_s *t, FILE *f, size_t len) {
   t->string = malloc(len);
   if (!t->string) return -1;
   if (scanf(....) != 1) return -2;
   return 0;
}

// represents an array of things
struct thingsarr_s {
    struct thethings_s *things;
    size_t w;
    size_t h;
};
int thigsarr_load_from_file(struct thingsarr_s *t, FILE *f) {
    // Initialize t->w and t->h.
    t->things = malloc(t->w * sizeof(*t->things));
    if (!arr) return -1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < w; ++i) {
       if (thething_load_from_file(&t->things[i], f, t->h) != 0) {
          for (size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
             thethings_free(t->things[j]);
          }
          free(t->things);
          return -1000 - i;
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
const struct thething_s *thingsarr_get_thing(const struct thingsarr_s *t, size_t idx)
{
   assert(idx < t->len);
   return t->things[idx];
}
struct thething_s *thingsarr_get_thing_nonconst(struct thingsarr_s *t, size_t idx) {
   return (struct thething_s *)thingsarr_get_thing(t, idx);
}
void thingsarr_free(struct thingsarr_s *t) {
  for (.,.) {
     thething_free(&t->things[i]);
  }
  free(t->things);
}
```

Which is "best" strongly depends on the context, specific needs and specific application.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer types `char **` and `char (*)[w]` are very different. There is a common misconception that arrays and pointers are the same thing in C, but that is not the case.

You want the return type of the function to be `char (*)[w]`, but that return type is impossible to declare because `w` is an unknown value. Also, the caller doesn't know the width and height of the returned array, because that information is internal to the `loadArray` function.

Setting the return type of the `loadArray` function to `void*` allows it to just return a pointer to the array without knowing the width or height. The width and height values can be sent to the caller using pointer arguments so that the caller can reconstruct the array type.

The following modifications of the original C code implements the above change. (C++ does not support variable length array types as far as I know, so this is C only.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* loadArray(int *pw, int *ph) {
    FILE *in = fopen("file", "r");

    int w, h;
    fscanf(in, "%d %d\n", &w, &h);
    *pw = w;
    *ph = h;
    char (*buf)[w] = malloc(sizeof(char[h][w]));

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        fscanf(in, "%s\n", buf[i]);
    }

    fclose(in);

    return buf;
}

int main(void) {
    int w, h;
    void* larray = loadArray(&w, &h);
    char(*array)[w] = larray;
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```